# Realex Payment Redirect Issue - 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: php, vps, realex-payments-api

I have recently moved servers and am having issues with our payment module since the move. We moved from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4.

We have a Realex Payment Module installed on xcart to process our payments, during checkout users are sent to a secure site to enter their payment details, the payment processes but they get the error: Your transaction has been successful but there was a problem connecting back to the merchant's web site

Realex have informed me that a 302 redirect is causing the problem, we have nothing in place to cause this redirect.

The following is the logs received from realex:

```
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction $response_uri = https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/store/payment/cc_realex_redirect.php 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction $num_remaining = 0 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction $client_return_url = https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/store/payment/cc_realex_redirect.php 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction $num_remaining = 0 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction Return URL: https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/store/payment/cc_realex_redirect.php 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction Client Host: www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction Client URLs: store/payment/cc_realex_redirect.php 
27.08.2013 17:02:18 carbonaction ..start POST request, UserAgent timeout set to 180 seconds.
27.08.2013 17:02:20 carbonaction ..end POST request, UserAgent returned the status: 302 Moved Temporarily
27.08.2013 17:02:20 carbonaction Error connecting to client site:Moved Temporarily
```

This works fine on the old server, we recently moved to a vps, could there be a potential server configuration issue here?

Thanks for your help.

Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I visit `https://www.energysavingwarehouse.co.uk/store/payment/cc_realex_redirect.php` a `302` redirect bounces me to `../`. This is probably because I'm doing a `GET` rather than a `POST` and there's no `POST` fields.

If you've upgraded to a newer version of PHP, it's possible that the configuration has changed and the code is no longer finding all the `POST` fields - previously `$HTTP_POST_VARS[]` was OK, but now you should use `$_POST[]`, and sometimes PHP can be configured to automatically create new variables for each `POST` field - e.g. `name=Owen` automatically creates a variable `$name` with the value `Owen`. In particular, the `register_globals` option was removed completely in 5.4.0 and you now need to explicitly declare variables in some situations where you didn't before (See http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Can you check the code in `cc_realex_redirect.php` to see what scenarios trigger the `302` redirect? This should look like:

```
header('Location: ../');
```

Then add some logging to ensure that all the `POST` data is being picked up correctly. This should lead you to the solution.